# My table having unique id, delete duplicate records

Tags: mysql, sql

[In this image there are two kavya with differnt id's ... but every field same for that 2 rows... I need to echeck atleast 5 fields and if those five fileds are found to be same means i want to delete one row and keep one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZkPi.png)In my database duplicate records are stored.. every columns except id is same for two rows... now i need to delete one record among the two duplicate records and keep one safe

Comment: Not an unusual request on this site try searching for mysql delete duplicate (and try something).

Answer (score 0):

```
Delete from table_Name A
Where exists (select 1 
From table_Name B
Where A.id = B.id
);
```

Comment: This does not work in MySQL, because you cannot refer to the table being deleted elsewhere in the query.

Comment: i have only one table

Comment: you have put all column name in where clouse

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can use `join` with `delete`:

```
delete t
    from t join
         (select t.col1, t.col2, . . . ., min(t.id) as min_id
          from t
          group by t.col1, t.col2, . . .
         ) tt
         using (col1, col2, . . . )
    where t.id > tt.min_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want something like:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_name WHERE condition LIMIT 1
```

The condition will find the two rows. The `LIMIT` will delete just one of them.

Read up on MySQL's `[DELETE][1]`.

Comment: i am having doubt in that condition only